# do not understand if else block behaviour

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim a As Integer = 8 * 60
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    If a < (6 * 60) Then
        b = 0 And c = 0
    ElseIf a >= 6 * 60 And a < 9 * 60 Then
        b = 30 And c = 1
    Else
        b = 45 And
       c = 1
    End If
    MsgBox(b)
End Sub
```

Thinks i dont understand and where i need someones help:

1. "c=0" and "c=1" are underlined with the error: Strict on doesnt allow implicit convertation from boolean to integer. WHY? I declared c as integer!
2. Variable "b" and "c" are always "0" even though in the case above they should be b=30 and c = 1.

can anyone please explain me this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `And` keyword where it is not allowed. `And` is a logical operator (along with `Or`, `AndAlso`, `OrElse`.)

The following should work.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim a As Integer = 8 * 60
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    If a < (6 * 60) Then
        b = 0
        c = 0
    ElseIf a >= 6 * 60 And a < 9 * 60 Then
        b = 30
        c = 1
    Else
        b = 45
        c = 1
    End If
    MsgBox(b)
End Sub
```